# How do I come up with an equation that will describe the results of other integrals with changes to a constant?

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I have one equation: 10*(1-x)(x^n)+(x)(1-x^n), to which I must find the integral of from [0,1], with n ranging from 1 to 100. I want to then plot the results with the x value as the value of n and the y value as the result of the integrals for each corresponding n value. What would the final equation that graphs the results be?
[image: This is what the graph looks like]

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematica.SE]!  Are you specifically interested in using the software program Mathematica to create this plot?  If not, and this question is more about the mathematics underlying this equation, you might be better off asking this question at [Math.SE] instead, which is about mathematics in general.

Comment: Please add to your question the Mathematica code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[n_] = Integrate[10*(1 - x) (x^n) + (x) (1 - x^n), {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> n > 0]
Plot[f[n], {n, 1, 100}]
```

gives back $$f(n)=\frac{n^2+n+20}{2 n^2+6 n+4}$$
and
[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to solve this! However, the graph does not seem to be aligned with my graphs! I edited my post to include what the graph looks like.

Comment: @vivianweng they do align, look at the y-axis. You can adjust this using `PlotRange` in the `Plot` command.

Comment: Sorry,  my mistake! Is there any way to tell how the equation was derived?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the graphs are aligned. I used PlotRange to match your graph and they look similar. I added to the solution given by bRost03.

```
Plot[f[n], {n, 1, 130}, PlotRange -> {{0, 160}, {0, 2}}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 160, 20], Range[0, 2, .20]}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 160, 20], Range[0, 2, .20]}]
```

[image]